# Using VBA to search data in Excel for a specific word, copy that row and 2 rows above and below into a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, row, spreadsheet, copying

I am looking for some help with a large set of data I have. I need to be able to search the data for a particular word (using an input box), then specify how many rows above and below this row appears (again using an input box) to also select. These rows need to be copied to a new sheet, which I was hoping would be named after the original search value.

So far I have this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
a = Worksheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
nr = Application.InputBox("Enter customer name to find", "SEARCH VALUE")
        If nr = False Then Exit Sub

For i = 2 To a

If Worksheets("Database").Cells(i, 4).Value = nr Then

    Worksheets("Database").Rows(i).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("Database").Activate

End If

Next

End Sub
```

What I have so far is very basic and only copies the select row and inputs the row into an already existing sheet -Sheet2.

I understand there are other posts on here about copying rows to new sheets but I have not found one yet that has two sets of criteria (one for the text and the second for number of rows above and below) and to also name the new sheet after the first search variable.

Comment: I edited my Answer. may please have a look. Also for further query regarding your original question I think it is better to Edit your original question and/or Comment, instead of posting another answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the additional help from Ahmed AU, I have managed to solve the problem.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
a = Worksheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
nr = Application.InputBox("Enter customer code", "SEARCH VALUE")
    If nr = False Then Exit Sub

N = InputBox("Enter additional number of rows", "Offset")
    If N = "" Then Exit Sub
    N = Val(N)

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = nr
Worksheets("Database").Activate

For i = 2 To a

If Worksheets("Database").Cells(i, 4).Value = nr Then


Srow = IIf(i - N <= 0, i, i - N)
Erow = i + N
Worksheets("Database").Rows(Srow & ":" & Erow).Copy
Worksheets(nr).Activate
b = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Worksheets("Database").Activate


End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try, after 1st inputbox

```
N = InputBox("Enter Number of Rows Above or below", "Offset")
        If N = "" Then Exit Sub
N = Val(N)
```

Then after if ... Then

```
Srow = IIf(i - N <= 0, i, i - N)
Erow = i + N
Worksheets("Database").Rows(Srow & ":" & Erow).Copy
```

Edit 2: wrt addition of new Worksheet, I think the code added by you is ok. But better to check if already there is any sheet named 'nr'
May try any of the followings as per your requirement

```
have = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = nr Then have = True
    Next

    If have = False Then
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = nr
    End If
```

OR

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name = nr Then ws.Delete
Next
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = nr
```

Comment: Thank you that has helped me with inputting the number of lines. I am still struggling to create a new sheet. I thought I had it but I ended up creating a new sheet for every entry found. Any advice on this would be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I was just about to look into making sure no other sheet has the same name. Thank you for adding this. Much appreciated.